# Should a wrong parameter passed via REST call throw an error?

Tags: rest

I was accessing REST calls, when I passed wrong parameter to GET request it does not throw any http error. Should the design be changed to throw a http error or wrong parameter can be passed to REST call.

Example 1:(parameters are optional)
https://example.com/api/fruits?fruit=apple

Give list of all apple elements

Example 2:
https://example.com/api/fruits?abc=asb

Give list of all fruits

My question is related to example 2, should example 2 throw an error or is it behaving properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's pretty common to ignore parameters that you aren't necessarily expecting. I think example 2 is behaving as it should.

I know that depending on the browser I would sometimes append an extra variable with a timestamp to make sure that the rest call wouldn't be cached. Something like:

```
https://example.com/api/fruits?ihateie=2342342342
```

If you're not explicitly doing anything with the extra parameter then I can't see the harm in allowing it.

Comment: In addition, have a look at [Postel's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle) , but you should also have a look at some [critiques](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-thomson-postel-was-wrong-00).

Comment: I've never heard of the robustness principle. Thanks for posting that!

Answer (score 0):

For a GET request, the [request-line is defined](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.1.1) as follows

```
request-line   = 'GET' SP request-target SP HTTP-version CRLF
```

where *request-target* "...identifies the target resource upon which to apply the request".

That means that the path `/api/fruits`, the question-mark `?` and the query `abc=asb` are *all* part of the identifier.

The fact that your implementation happens to use the path to route the request to a handler, and the query to provide arguments, is an accident of your current implementation.

That leaves you with the freedom to decide that

1. `/api/fruits?abc=asb` does exist, and its current state is a list of all fruits
2. `/api/fruits?abc=asb` does exist, and its current state is an empty list
3. `/api/fruits?abc=asb` does exist, and its current state is something else
4. `/api/fruits?abc=asb` does *not* exist, and attempting to access its current state is an error.

> My question is related to example 2, should example 2 throw an error or is it behaving properly?

If `abc=asb` indicates that there is some sort of error in the client, then you should return a 4xx status to indicate that.

Another way of thinking about the parameter handling is in terms of [Must Ignore vs Must Understand](https://martinfowler.com/articles/consumerDrivenContracts.html).

As a practical matter, if I'm a consumer expecting that my filter is going to result in a small result set, and instead I end up drinking a billion unfiltered records out of a fire hose, I'm not going to be happy.

I'd recommend that in the case of a bad input you find a way to fail safely.  On the web, that would probably mean a 404, with an HTML representation explaining the problem, enumerating recognized filters, maybe including a web form that helps resend the query, etc.  Translate that into your API in whatever way makes sense.

But choosing to treat that as a successful request and return some representation also *works*, it's still REST, the web is going to web.  If doing it that way gives you consumers a better experience, thereby increasing adoption and making your api more successful, then the answer is easy.